# Customer ListView with delete icon

Tags: android, animation, android-listview

I have ListView with customer Adapter,my listView rows should animate when i click Edit Button and show delete icon in each row.

All rows make animation and show delete icon, but first hidden item doesn't change until I scroll list down and i see it when animate.

how can I make all List items animate in the same time ?

I put animation code in CustomerAdapter Class in getView method.

Code:

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null){

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout,parent,false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id._title_textview);          

        holder.content=(LinearLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.content_layout);

        holder.deleteIcon=(LinearLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.delete_layout);

        holder.img=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id._main_img);

        view.setTag( holder );
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();


    if(MainActivity.click_edit_btn)
        {
            animation_right_to_left(holder.content_layout);
            holder.deleteIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    if(MainActivity.click_done_btn)
        {
            animation_left_to_right(holder.content_layout);
            holder.deleteIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    if(data.size()<=0)
        holder.title.setText("No Data");
    else
    {
        tempValues=null;
        tempValues = ( ListItemModel ) data.get( position );

        holder.title.setText( tempValues.getTitle() );
        holder.type.setText( tempValues.getType() );

    }
    return view;
}
```

Activity Code:

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .

```
    adapter = new CustomerAdapter( CustomListView, listData ,res );

    list.setAdapter( adapter );

    edit_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            click_edit_btn = true;
            click_done_btn = false;

            adapter.notifydatasetchanged();

        }
    });

    delete_done_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            click_edit_btn = false;
            click_done_btn = true;

            adapter.notifydatasetchanged();
        }
    });

    }
```

Comment: you could leave some code to see well

Comment: @Amjad welcome to StackOverFlow. As pointed out in the first comment, for people to be able to provide appropriate solutions to your question, question needs to be clearer and provide codes so people can have a look at and easily locate the problem.

Comment: @Want2bExpert ,sioesi Thanks,I edited my question.

Comment: Try to call youradapter.notifydatasetchanged() after list.setAdapter  in your activity or fragment class.

Comment: I did that but nothing changed

Comment: What's the last else for by the way. I believe this  if(click_done_btn) represent button.onClickListener?

Comment: sorry I edited code, I forget copy some lines .... (click_done_btn) mean i finished delete items and i want hide delete icons. I paste Activity code in question.

Comment: Try and have a new handler in each onClickListener that update the View when button is cliecked

Comment: I found this explain of "ListView recycling mechanism" stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/… that will explain the problem ... thank you for help @Wants2bExpert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link explain How ListView work ... it's about list

[How ListView's recycling mechanism works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works)

thanks @Muhammad Babar